# How do I advance past the quest Forging Alliances in Stick of Truth?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I haven't been focusing on the main quest. I spoke to the goth kids before I got the quest from Cartman, and now they won't say anything when I hit "A" to talk to them. The hobo hasn't started selling their clothes yet so I can't blend in with them. This feels like a bug to me, but I don't know how to fix it. I've looked at all of the walkthroughs for the quest and they all say the same thing.

How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make the mean goth kids talk to me and be my friends?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158726/how-can-i-make-the-mean-goth-kids-talk-to-me-and-be-my-friends)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of this question. I've tried all of the solutions posted there but they don't work.

Comment: @user93485 - It's still a duplicate because you're asking the same thing.  The *answers* might not work for you, but it's the same question.  (It very well could be a bug if you're already far enough in the game for it to have been triggered)

Comment: Ok, but my post and the other post aren't really asking the same thing. I'm stuck at the same point in the game, yeah, but the circumstances are different. I would have left a comment in the other thread but it requires more reputation to post.

Comment: My biggest issue is that when I hit "A" next to the kids, nothing happens at all. they've already told me to go buy nonconformist clothes but the clothes don't appear at the hobo. I still have Cartman's letter in my inventory.

Comment: Just to make sure: do you have a quest in your list called "Recruit the Goth Kids", with a subquest called "Noncomformist"? And you're talking to the hobo beneath the big U-Stor-It sign?

Comment: I have the quest "Recruit the Goth Kids" but not "Noncomformist". I have the letter in my inventory, but when I hit A next to the goth kids they don't say anything, not even a casual dismissive remark or anything. Can I use console commands or something to fix this bug?

Comment: Try doing some of the other parts of the quest. Are you able to buy the coffee from tweak's shop? are you able to get the cigarettes?